# What type of object is a map from 2D to 4D?

Tags: vector-analysis

A vector function $\mathbf V : \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^4$ I think is a surface because it as a parameterization has two parameters. But if I think for example if it is projected into $\Bbb R^3$ it may appear as a volume?

Comment: It won't appear as a volume, because a volume will require three parameters (which it will have two, even when projected to $\mathbb R^3$.  It will be a surface.

Comment: If $\mathbf V(x_0,x_1)=\langle u(x_0,x_1),v(x_0,x_1),w(x_0,x_1),z(x_0,x_1) \rangle$ and is projected to $x_0,x_2,x_3$ for a vector say $\langle a,b,c,d \rangle$ and $\langle a,b_2,c,d \rangle$ because the $x_1$ isn't graphed, it could be used to get a volume? Sorry I'm trying to think how to say this correctly.

Comment: I guess in $\Bbb R^4$ there is always a ball around a $\mathbf V$ value such that it contains a point which is not in in $\mathbf V$ however in some $\Bbb R^3$ this isn't the case maybe if one dependent axis is left out?

Comment: You can't get a volume out of $\mathbb R^2$ (almost by definition of what a surface is - it's an object that's very similar to $\mathbb R^2$ at each point) - you can get surfaces that self-intersect/aren't "embeddable" in $\mathbb R^3$ (but are completely fine in $\mathbb R^4$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function is suitably nice, it will indeed be a surface, and projecting into $\mathbb R^3$ will *at most* again give a surface, which however may intersect itself. However in special cases, the projection might instead be a curve (if the surface happens to be orthogonal to the $\mathbb R^3$ it is projected to) or even a curve near some points and a surface near others. It cannot, however, be a volume (but see below).

As analogy, consider curves in $\mathbb R^3$, which are continuous functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R^3$. If they are suitably nice, then projecting to $\mathbb R^2$ will still give a curve, not an area.

However note that there *are* non-nice functions. For example, you can have a *surjective* function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^4$. Projecting that to $\mathbb R^3$ of course gives all of $\mathbb R^3$. Such a surjective function cannot be continuous, though.

But there can be also continuous functions that are "pathological". Consider [space-filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve) which are continuous, but densely fill a two-dimensional subset of $\mathbb R^2$. The Cartesian product of two such functions give an analogous map from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^4$, and the projection to $\mathbb R^3$ then of course also will be space-filling.

Comment: Very interesting the space filling curves.

Answer (score 2):

A [surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)) in math is a "two dimensional manifold", meaning each point "Looks a lot like $\mathbb R^2$".  By that definition, if you have a map $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^4$ that's "nice" in a suitable way (continuous with continuous inverse), it will be a "two dimensional manifold".

Now, there can be two dimensional manifolds with *very* weird "projections into $\mathbb R^3$".  The prototypical example of this is the [Klein Bottle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_bottle) - this is a two dimensional manifold (a surface) that can't be put in $\mathbb R^3$ without intersecting itself.  It *can* be put into $\mathbb R^4$ with no issue though.

So, it depends on what your map is - if your map isn't assumed continuous at all, we no longer can say any of the above.